# Are paper airplanes on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

Considering that origami is an art, and paper airplanes are basically the same, except that you make airplanes with the paper and throw them, is paper airplane making within the scope of crafts.se?

Comment: You were too quick accepting an answer with just one opinion and no convincing vote count. Meta questions should draw some discussion.

Comment: @CamilStaps I unaccepted it.

Comment: Meta is one place where I feel like the accepted answer feature doesn't even make sense. You can accept the lowest voted one, if you feel like it! I personally don't see the point in bothering.

Answer (score 7):

### Yes, absolutely, the same as any other paper or modeling craft.

Just as you said, it's a folding paper art. It's also about making models. We've established origami as on topic, and paper crafting. I expect model making will be on topic. Paper airplanes fit into any one of these, so there's no reason to exclude them.

However, the questions should be about the craft itself, and not trivia such as "What's the largest paper airplane ever made?"

And not about making specific models, such as "How do I make a B-52 bomber?", same as with origami where "How can I make a paper giraffe?" wouldn't be allowed.

But "What can I add to my paper airplane to make the point sturdier without adding much weight?" or "Reliably tape parts to paper airplane without creating imbalance" should have a place here.

Comment: If someone can write an answer justifying why paper airplanes would be off topic when origami and model making are on topic, please do so. Maybe it'll help explain this down vote.

Comment: I suggest editing the heading to "It depends", because you also give examples of questions that would not belong here.

Comment: @Camil I really don't see the point, because they're the same examples we'd use for any craft, really. It's the same scope of on topicness as the rest.

Comment: It's simply that your heading doesn't fit the body.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes, absolutely.** As the person who's been asking most of the origami questions, I'd actually think of it as an origami sub-category, say, like kusudama, unit origami, rezuru, tesselations, microgami, currency/business card/gum wrapper, or free-form origami, that has its own special issues/techniques.  I would, however, recommend *tagging* it as paper-airplane to be able to pull out the paper aircraft specific questions from the rest of the origami "noise".

The main thing is that the questions should probably be about the physical creation (folding, materials) of the airplane, while questions solely about aerodynamics of paper aircraft might be better served on aviation.SE or physics.SE.  Issues in designing said aircraft might be a toss-up.

See:

- [paper-airplane tag on aviation.SE](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/search?q=paper-airplane).
- [paper-airplane tag on physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=paper-airplane).